# Securely hide OS independent a directory using java

Tags: java, linux

I have a project to do for my master degree and I need to do a java app which load a file (read some attributes and copy the file to a working directory), basically any file, and make the working directory private. By private I mean to hide in a way that directory from any OS (well, bascially Windows and Linux). I'm not sure that the OS (Windows and Linux) functions to hide directories work because an admin/superuser can modify those settings and easily access my files.

The idea for the project is to have exclusive access to those loaded files from within the app and to make them available for the aplications installed locally to open/run them (like "Open in media player"), which should work also when I copy the app to a USB stick.
I have 2 options: 
1) modify each file after loading to make unreadable to the world and undo the modifications each time I press "Open" from within the app; 
2) (which i think is the best and most simple option) Modify the root directory of those files (root = the working directory or some subdirectory of it) to be unreadable/unaccessible to the world while outside the app and readable to the app at the runtime.

I've been thinking about something like making a locally encripted copy of filesystem attributes of the directory, "delete" them while not at app runtime and put them back while at app runtime. But I didn't really played with this before and also Windows&Linux filesystems aren't simple at all. More of it, a USB stick have a FAT filesystem (which if I'm not wrong "belongs" to DOS), which is, yeah, another filesystem into the equation.

I'm almost sure it is not feasible (and not secure!) to simply play back and forth with the filesystem as my pleasure, so I need some ideas to find that breakthrough without actually breaking anything.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I've found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html) in the SE8 docs while searching for something helpfull in the java library. As soon as I'm not interested of reinventing "the wheel" of filesystems, just to make some little tricks with mine, it might provide what I need.

Comment: Are you confident that you can keep a secret?  If so you could do a [file-system within an encrypted file](http://uranus.chrysocome.net/linux/ex2fsfile.htm).  Also, security.stackexchange might be a good forum for this kind of question.

Comment: About the only way to do it is to set up your own primitive file system either in another (encrypted) file or in a private (& encrypted) partition that you access via native methods or some such.

Comment: I've been also thinking about doing a filesystem, but sounds like a complex idea and I want to make sure I've exhausted all other simpler ones. Thanks!

Comment: @HotLicks, as far as I analyzed the problem, that's about the only solution I've also found.

Comment: What is the difference between an (super)user who can access the working directory compared to a (super)user who can access your app, execute it and gain access to the working directory? IMHO there is no difference, hence your app has no impact on the security as long as there is not a secret the (super)user does not know or has no access to (secret is stored e.g. in a local TPM or so).

Comment: There is a difference between a (super)user who can acces the working directory (assuming that the working directory here contains directly my files) and one that can acces, execute my app & gain access to the dir. The second one can execute the file through my app. About gaining the access to the dir while the app is running, thank God it is not a real life app! Otherwise I would've probably been working in a sotware secutiry company or so. :)